# How to apply similar RDD reduceByKey on Dataframes

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, rdd

I am working with Spark and specially with Spark SQL over Dataframes because it have many optimizations over traditional RDDs; almost all things that you could do in RDD, you can do in Dataframes. My problem is:

I have a dataframe with 2 fields. The first is the key (K) and the second is the value (V). So, i have the following Dataframe

```
df.show()

| K | V |
---------
| 1 | a |
| 2 | b |
| 2 | c |
| 3 | d |
| 3 | e |
| 3 | f |
```

I want to transform it into:

```
| K |     V     |
-----------------
| 1 | [a]       |
| 2 | [b, c]    |
| 3 | [d, e, f] |
```

I know if I use:

```
df.rdd.map(lambda x: [x["K"], [x["V"]]]).reduceByKey(lambda a, b: a + b).toDF().show()
```

I will get the result, but on this way, I am using RDD transformation instead of Dataframe API.

There is some way to do it using **Dataframe operations only**? (Maybe using UDFs, agg functions, ...)

Comment: you want `df.groupBy("K").agg(collect_list("V"))` .. looking for a dupe

Comment: The console shows `NameError: name 'collect_list' is not defined`

Comment: you have to import it first: `from pyspark.sql.functions import collect_list`

Comment: Possible dupes: [Spark dataframes groupby into list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31864744/spark-dataframes-groupby-into-list), [Collect rows as list with group by apache spark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51124561/collect-rows-as-list-with-group-by-apache-spark),